# Are $p$-adic analytic Lie extensions asymptotically bad?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The *root discriminant* of a number field is defined to be the $n$-th root of
the absolute value of its discriminant, where $n$ is the degree of the number field.

Let $K$ be a number field and $L/K$ be an infinite extension. We say $L/K$ is *asymptotically good* if there is no infinite sequence of distinct intermediate subfields of $L/K$ with root discriminant tending to infinity, otherwise we say $L/K$ is *asymptotically bad*.

Are *infinite* $p$-adic Lie extensions always asymptotically bad?

Comment: $p$-adic Lie extension means an extension whose Galois closure has a Galois group that is a $p$-adic Lie group?

Comment: If the p-adic Lie extension is admissible i.e contains the cyclotomic Zp extension then clearly it is bad. In general being good is a strong hypothesis and in particular implies that the extension has finite ramification at p, one would expect that an infinite p-adic Lie extension of a number field is infinitely ramified at p if it is ramified at only finitely many primes. This is roughly the second version of the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture.

Comment: ... Martinet was the first to construct an infinitely unramified tower with small constant root discriminant. There are some interesting examples of good infinite extensions in "Tamely Ramified Towers and Discriminant bounds for Number fields"- Hajir and Maire.

Comment: ... An interesting aside: if one starts with a number field and builds a tower by taking the p Hilbert class field extension at step 1 and then getting from step n to step n+1 by taking the p Hilbert class field extension, it is of interest to know if such a process terminates at a finite stage.